# Capturing camel exchange data into database

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse

How would you recommend in Camel to define key/value expressions in routes for things you want to save for auditing, and have them be picked up and written to a database transparently?

i.e. the route contains an array or set of expressions for things to save for auditing, but doesn't know how it actually gets picked up and written to a DB.

This would be like Mule's auditing feature, where you can put `<flow>` elements in the Mule XML and define expressions to save to Mule's DB for tracking.

I have looked at Interceptor, Event Notifiers, Tracers, WireTaps, MDC Logging - I am sure the answer lies in one or a combination of these elements but it's not clear to me.

I'm using this example of Mule auditing XML from its documentation as a comparison:

```
<flow name="bizFlow">
    <tracking:custom-event event-name="Retrieved Employee" doc:name="Custom Business Event">
        <tracking:meta-data key="Employee ID" value="#[payload['ID']]"/>
        <tracking:meta-data key="Employee Email" value="#[payload['Email']]"/>
        <tracking:meta-data key="Employee Git ID" value="#[payload['GITHUB_ID']]"/>
    </tracking:custom-event>
</flow>
```

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

For auditing I used `wireTap` to send exchange to special `audit route` where I do what I need for auditing. Not actually to DB but to JMS queue, but it does not matter.

There is only one restriction: whatever goes for auditing must not be changed after `wireTap` by main route (both run in parallel), so I cloned such auditing data before `wireTap` to special Exchange property to be used in audit route.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - so in your case, you are creating a dedicated exchange property that stores auditing data, but you still have to explicitly add the wiretap to each route. I am wondering if there is a way to do this so you would only have to create the property and not have to put the wiretap in the route?

Comment: Yes you are rigth. I added wireTap at any places where I need to do auditing. It was what I exactly needed from auditing - audit what I need at points in flow where I need. i'm not sure what actually you need to audit and how, but there are two parameters in each route `trace` and `messageHistory`. As I remember messageHistory is also an exchange property and can be customized and handled as well. Also, I do not think there are more in Camel for such purpose. Maybe you can create such component and share it with community? how about it? -:)